# How to make registry edits take effect immediately

Tags: c#, registry

I'm building an application in C# where you can press a button and disable the USB ports on the system using the registry. However, the change seems to require a full restart for the disabling/re-enabling of the USBs. Is there any way to make the changes to the registry happen immediately after they are edited?

Comment: This is handled on a case-by-case basis. You need to read the documentation for the component that uses the registry key to see if they offer a way to perform the desired operation on the fly. (In this case, my guess is that you would call Configuration Manager rather than editing the registry directly.)

Comment: The registry isn't what requires a restart, whatever is using the setting is what requires the restart.